# How to change NULLS in decimal fields to show as " "

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the below to print any with nulls as `' '`:

```
CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(dbo.vwCumulativeGPA.GPA,' '), 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) AS 'CUM GPA'
```

I am missing something important.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `decimal` is a number why would you expect an empty value casted to a decimal not be `0`? I assume if you want `' '` that you shouldn't cast those as Decimals then.

Comment: They want those with no cumulative gpa's to show as blank - to distinguish them from students who do have bad cumulative gpa's as "0.000" (not all current students have taken classes before)

Comment: So return NULL from your query and have the front end display NULL as an empty string.

Comment: A column can have only one single data type. For ex. if you have customer_id column defined as int then it can have only int data type. you can not insert char or date inside customer_id. In you query you have GPA is defined as decimal and in case of null you want to change the data type from decimal to char ' ' which is not possible. If you still want to show ' ' in case of null then you need to change the whole output as char.  like - isnull( cast (CAST(ROUND(dbo.vwCumulativeGPA.GPA, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) as varchar(10)) ,'')  AS 'CUM GPA'

Answer (score 1):

`ROUND(' ', 3)` is `0` so the effect of the inner `ISNULL()` is lost.

For this to work rely on NULL propagation, the entire expression must also return a character type:

```
ISNULL(CAST(CAST(ROUND(vwCumulativeGPA.GPA, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ' ') AS 'CUM GPA'
```

This seems like a bad idea, it's best done in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Only string datatypes like varchar can have an empty space or space character as their value.

Decimal fields can only have NULL or decimals as their values.

If you cast your final column as a varchar, you can replace NULLS with `' '`.

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(7),(CAST(ROUND(dbo.vwCumulativeGPA.GPA, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3))),' ') AS 'CUM GPA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Should really be a presentation layer item, however, if 2012+ you can use format().

**Example**

```
IsNull(format(dbo.vwCumulativeGPA.GPA,'0.000'),' ')
```

Just a word of caution.  Format has some great functionality, but it is not known to be a performer.  In other words, **Use Sparingly**

Also, the `'0.000'` will round your value to 3 decimals and show trailing zeros